# Mutual information between sets of variables

Tags: mutual-information

I found in [this paper (PDF)](http://www.cs.umb.edu/~ding/papers/liICDM2013.pdf)
a mutual information between groups of variables such as these:

> - I(X;Y|F)
> - I(F;Y)
> - I(F;Y|G)

where F is a set of variables, and G is a set of sets of variables.
I am neither statistician nor mathematician, but I have a fair knowledge about mutual information, and I do know how to calculate mutual information between two variables I(X;Y) if we have $n$ samples of X and Y.
Can anyone help me do the same for the formulas above?
Thanks.

Comment: It may impact the kinds of answers that may be relevant -- what kind of approach would you tend to use to calculate $I(X; Y)$ between the $X$ and $Y$ observations in a sample of $n$ observations on $(X,Y)$?

Comment: I intend to use this [formula](https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/c/b/b/cbb518be041b820958181a932a5cd4ff.png). Th joint and marginal probabilities can be estimated by a kernel function (e.g. Gaussian or epanechnikov)